# Alternative/replacement of Firebase Jobdispatcher

Tags: android, firebase, android-syncadapter

recently came back to some Android dev, and since Nougat it seems that Firebase JobDispatcher isn't possible to be triggered more than once every 15 mins, which isn't applicable in our use case, we need to be able to push & pull data to our webservice at least once per minute.

What should/can I be using instead? I haven't been able to find a solid replacement yet, been looking into SyncAdapter, IntentService and what I've found they aren't really best applicable in this use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does JobScheduler have the 15 minute restriction? 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html . Firebase JobDispatcher is generally for the pre-Lollipop case where JobScheduler is not supported.

Comment: Yes, as per nougat JobScheduler has the same restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic Service

```
public class YourWebService extends Service {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Runnable runnable =  new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //your code here
                //web request, data push, something else
            }
        };  

        //your code will be executed every 60 seconds
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can start your service from activity

```
 startService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourWebService.class));
```

And you have to register your service in manifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".YourWebService" />
```

Comment: Thanks, we've used this implementation for now and seems to be solid.